# How to pop up some part image in android

Tags: android, image, imageview

i want to display the some part of image.like a comic book.i have one image like this.

[image: this is actual image.]

when i click on image some part display like this.

[image: Second image when click this part of image.]

i want to display this type.
in  this process i create some zip file witch contain the part of images of main image.
i done to  display every image sequence wise.but my problem is how to get the actual image's any part click and display this in like second screen?

i can't  get the image part id.
so how to get this part of image id.

so please help me.
i am stuck.

Comment: Same like clicking on facebook images, it will pop up full-image in new screen.

Comment: @PareshMayani but how to manage witch click is doen.it is every singal image not i combine like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have archive with parts of main image, so that means you made them manually, right?
So, your comics book viewer will be applicable only for manually created content.

It it's true, so there is no trouble to make some kind of config-file (for example xml-based or [Properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html) file) which will contain size and position for each part.

After that you can handle [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and detect id of part by coordinates from config.

You also can improve your application by cutting images on-fly. It's not difficult.

Example:

Your image here (`page1.png`):

```
--------------------------------
|                 |            |
|                 |            |
|                 |     2      |
|        1        |            |
|                 |            |
|                 |------------|
|                 |            |
|-----------------|            |
|                 |     4      |
|                 |            |
|                 |            |
|                 |------------|
|        3        |            |
|                 |            |
|                 |     5      |
|                 |            |
|                 |            |
--------------------------------
```

Your simple config (`page1.cfg`):

```
# Parts description
# id=x,y;w,h
1=0,0;18,9
2=19,0;13,7
3=0,10;18,11
4=19,8;13,7
5=19,15;13,6
```

Your zip:

```
page1.png
page1-1.png
page1-2.png
page1-3.png
page1-4.png
page1-5.png
page1.cfg
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but how to manage whole book it`s not only singal page it's one book.so how can i detect this.

Comment: You can detect parts of pages on fly. There are many algorithms. At first you should detect your background. After that you can detect vertical and horizontal dividers on your page, use heuristics.

Comment: I think extracting edges and parts is separate task. And this is too complex task. Actually, you do not need to cut your page. You can detect key points and use them as offset. So, your Bitmap instance will be single and you will move them by offsets.

Answer (score 0):

you can do One Trick for this Problem.

> **Set Buttons(With Background as Transparent) inside layouts.**
>
> Set OnclickListener of buttons to Show your PopUps which you want
>   inside your class activity.
>
> you can also manage button Click Event by Visible/Invisible Feature to
>   as per your requirement.

**Edited**

your xml will look like as below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_invisible"
        android:layout_width="85dp" 
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Inside your OnCreate() Method of your Activity Class.

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    setContentView(R.layout.help_1);
    btn_invisible = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_invisible);
    btn_invisible.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v == btn_invisible) {
        //Whatever Code you want to Use for Show Popups

    }
```

I am not sure but you can try it out once.

Comment: but see the image it`s like different and how to set the image button randomaly?i know to create a dyanamic layout but how to store this button below actual part of image.

Comment: i have edited my answer with description of code. let me know if this helps you.

Comment: i think it's some idea i try then give u response dear.